# Why won't Crusader Kings 2 give me my land?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I had a claim on 3 different counties, courtesy of my late mother, and I fought a brutal war against the owner of them(England) after I won the game said I gained my new territory as usually but after that the land remained under British control, the titles of them were in my character page, but the titles were also on the King of England's character page.
  I even reloaded and conquered them all over again but the glitch persists. Has anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 5):

Just found the problem. I misread the claims, turns out i only gained control of the duchies, not the land itself. Weird but not actually a glitch.